# What are Barrel and Pincushion distortion and how are they corrected?

Tags: lens, optics, distortion

I have some questions regarding barrel distortion and pincushion distortion. Since they are related I have put them in single post.

1. I am aware that barrel distortion
   occurs more in wide-angle 
   lenses, wherein straight lines near
   edges of the frame curve outwards.
   Is it pincushion distortion when
   lines curve inward, and in what
   conditions (what types of lenses, etc.) does 
   pincushion distortion occur?
2. I am aware that some new
   cameras (DSLRs, DSCs, SLDs) have
   in-camera corrections for these
   distortions, and also there are some
   tools to correct it in post
   processing (e.g., PTlens) but what is the
   exact procedure used in the
   correction process? Does the
   correction process work in Raw Bayer
   domain, or after some color
   conversion to YCbCr?

Any pointers (especially for question 2) would be useful, as I am trying to implement one post process for this type of correction.

Comment: Just a nit-pick, fisheye lenses use a different projection which makes all lines curved unless they cross the center of the frame. People do not normally refer to that as *barrel distortion*, since it is intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your interpretation of distortion is correct. For an example of a lens that exhibits barrel distortion at the wide angle and pin cushion distortion at the telephoto end, have a look at the [Canon 18-135mm](http://www.photozone.de/canon-eos/462-canon_18135_3556is?start=1)
2. Tools like PTLens and Hugin perform the corrections after the demosaicing of the Bayer data. I'm not sure why this would matter?

If you're interested in understanding how this correction is done, the equations are presented [here](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Lens_correction_model.html).