# How do straight edges end up curved in photos?

Tags: lens, optics, distortion

In the standard model for a lens straight lines in the subject of a photograph will always end up straight. However I have seen a variety of photographs in which straight lines end up being curved, e.g. the horizon tapers down at the edges, or a fence near the photo border is mildly curved.

What could cause straight edges to come out curved in a photograph? I have no idea what cameras were used in these cases, but I am certain they are standard consumer grade cameras (so they aren't fisheye type lenses such as equisolid angle lenses). Believe it or not I have to make computations based around objects in photographs and have no way of accounting for why straight things turn out curved in some photographs. From what I know about optics, this shouldn't happen, but it does, so I am missing something. What is it?

Can anyone give authoritative information about this?

Comment: It is barrel and pincushion distortion. Wide angle lenses also have perspective distortion. I believe you can find a great deal of information on this site on these topics already.

Comment: Like [What are Barrel and Pincushion distortion and how are they corrected?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11054/what-are-barrel-and-pincushion-distortion-and-how-are-they-corrected)

Comment: Signpost!      (filler text)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into those. Don't know what to do about an official question answer.

Comment: You can leave it unanswered, it can be closed as a duplicate, or you can read the other topics, and answer your own question, if no one else does in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get completely straight lines using a pinhole camera. As soon as you put a lens element in the path of the light, you get the fisheye-like distortion to some degree.

Modern lenses contain several lens elements which compensate for each other to give straight lines, but you usually get a slight distortion anyway. For really expensive lenses you have a very small distortion, but it's still there.

Comment: Didn't know that. By fisheye like distortion do you mean that a single parabolic lens has barrel distortion?